# How to import and use chart.js-plugin-labels-dv in Angular 2

Tags: angular, chart.js

how can I use chart.js-plugin-labels-dv (https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js-plugin-labels-dv)  and import it to my angular project to show my percentage labels outside pie chart?

```
public pieChartPlugins: any = [DatalabelsPlugin]

  public pieChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          let sum = 0
          let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data
          dataArr.map((data) => {
            if (data !== 0) {
              // @ts-ignore
              sum += data
            }
          })
          let percentage = ((value * 100) / sum).toFixed(2) + '%'
          return percentage
        },
        color: '#FFF',
      },
    },
  }


  <canvas baseChart
            [data]="pieChartData"
            [type]="pieChartType"
            [options]="pieChartOptions"
            [plugins]="pieChartPlugins"
            >
    </canvas>
```

Comment: This question is NOT related to "chartjs-plugin-annotation".